# "Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: status code: 500"

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I am using an asp.net text box inside ajax update panel. If I enter &#  in the textbox and press Save Button , it gives a javascript error

> Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 500

Please help me why this error appears?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881470/sys-webforms-pagerequestmanagerservererrorexception-an-unknown-error-occurred-w)

Answer (score 7):

Probably [ASP.NET Request Validation](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/request-validation) kicked in and detected a potentially dangerous request (the &# in the textbox value). This causes an `HttpRequestValidationException` to be thrown - hence the 500 HTTP code is returned by the UpdatePanel. The way I see it there are two ways to solve this problem:

1. Validate the contents of the textbox and replace any potentially dangerous (HTML like) values.
2. Disable request validation:

   `<%@ Page ValidateRequest="false" %>`

If you choose to disable request validation make sure that the value of this textbox is not output verbatim somewhere else in your application. Make sure you are using [HttpUtility.HtmlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmlencode.aspx) when displaying it in order to avoid [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) issues.